# Analog circuit to avg. op-amp values over time?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, analog

Is it possible and any advice on how to design an analog circuit at the output of an op-amp that averages the values for a time period at a given "sampling" rate?

Eg. averaging 1000 values over a period of 1 s and then the ADC will sample this average. The goal is to reduce the random noise, so will be a better option if this is possible with an analog circuit itself instead of sampling with an ADC.

Comment: A fairly simple analogue low-pass filter can perform a "near-enough" rolling average. But ,why can't you average in the digital realm?

Comment: Hi Andy, Higher sampling rate in the ADC will increase the noise. Looking for more precision. The goal is to average the signal in order minimize random noise. This will require a lot of samples, at very high sample rates the ADC noise increases a lot. What do you mean by "near-enough", will you please elaborate?

Comment: @Joel Andy is just saying that you can 'analog average' (as with capacitors, for example) or you can do it digitally in software (if the noise exceeds quantization.) But the best way to minimize noise is to design the transducer input stage, optimally. That requires detailed knowledge of the transducer, circumstances of ambient physics impacting it, and matching it up with the right electronic devices at the 1st stage. Once noise is let in, you are stuck with banal tradeoffs. But there's usually a lot you can do before that happens.

Comment: You write "averaging 1000 values", but unless you go to a lot of extra effort and complication, an opamp circuit doesn't have discrete values to average. It's a 'continuous-time' system, not a 'discrete-time' sampling system.

Comment: Averaging to reduce noise is kind of a misnomer. Try re-conceptualizing things to the noise frequencies you want to remove and it will reconcile much better with analog filter circuits.

Yes, averaging filters are a thing, but the exact idea of an average is way overspecified for your needs, which makes the implementation more complex than it needs to be, especially analog implementations. You're probably just looking for an RC lowpass filter after you discard the notion of averaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching this backwards. Usually one starts with the number of unique measurements per second they want (e.g. 10 Hz) and then uses the Nyquist criteria to pick a sampling rate at least twice as high (20 or 30 Hz). Finally you set a low pass filter to restrict how fast the signal can change to 10 Hz.

In reality real analog filters do not cut off exactly at a single frequency so the sampling rate is often set much higher and then a digital low pass filter is selected to set the precise cut off frequency.

You mentioned that you wanted to keep the sampling rate low to avoid noise, but this is a bad idea. You should run it faster and use a digital low pass filter to reduce noise introduced by higher sampling rates. Trying to keep the sampling rate low will actually make things worse, so typically it is set as high as possible. For example, in high sensitivity audio applications, it is common to run the ADC or DAC at 128, 256 or even 1024x times the Nyquist rate and then filter digitally in order to give precise control over frequency cutoff and maximize noise rejection.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Can you please share any link(s) regarding the audio application?

Comment: @Joel There are many topics here on oversampling and how it is used, but off hand I don't have a good reference beyond the terse descriptions in typical datasheet ('the conversion clock and digital filter operate at 256x the output sampling rate').